# Apache Tomcat Still Looking for Uninstalled Java Version

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have jasperserver running on apache tomcat on a web application. I have Java version 1.4 installed and the correct JAVA_HOME environment variable set. I can get to "myurl:8080" just fine and it shows the apache tomcat page. Originally i installed java 1.8 which seemed to be incompatible for my old version of jasperserver.

I needed to install an older version of Java, so i uninstalled 1.8 and installed 1.4 on my linux instance for my Java App. However, when i try and connect to jasperserver through the app, it seems like it is still looking in the old directory for old java library. How can i configure this to look at my new directory in same location? The error is below.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar

The correct version of java is located below.

/usr/lib/jvm/java1.4.2_18/

Comment: Check typing java --version command to see where it is pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the java_home and jre_home environment variables path,if you update
java version.The environment variables need to be edited.
[Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjer-Wp5MXOAhULt48KHfuKCgEQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.java.com%2Fen%2Fdownload%2Fhelp%2Fpath.xml&usg=AFQjCNFbBGPu7u8p-_kTCSnL_32BMZ_mnA&sig2=U6CqSryVQF6CF7vJchZ95Q) is how to change or edit the environment variables